# can not get file using nginx

Tags: nginx

I am trying to get img using nginx. My nginx config is here:
listen       80;
        server_name  *.test.com;

```
    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://test_com;
    } 
    location ^~ /img {
         root /data/img;
    }
```

I put test.html file into the /data/img dir.But when I request http://www.test.com/img/test.html, 404 happened

Is there something wrong about my config file?

thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File name to serve is `root` + `uri`, i.e. `/data/img` + `/img/test.html` with your config.  Most likely you mean `/data/img/test.html` instead.  Use this instead:

```
location /img {
    root /data;
}
```

See http://nginx.org/r/root for details.